# Position subscribe button in the bottom of a form

Tags: html, css

I know almost nothing about CSS.

This is my table:

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td class="onefield acyfield_1 acyfield_text">
         <label class="cell margin-top-1">
            <div class="acym__users__creation__fields__title">Name</div>
            <input name="user[name]" value="" data-authorized-content="{&quot;0&quot;:&quot;all&quot;,&quot;regex&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;message&quot;:&quot;Incorrect value for the field Name&quot;}" type="text" class="cell  ">
         </label>
         <div class="acym__field__error__block" data-acym-field-id="1"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="onefield acyfield_2 acyfield_text">
         <label class="cell margin-top-1">
            <div class="acym__users__creation__fields__title">Email</div>
            <input id="email_field_403" name="user[email]" value="" data-authorized-content="{&quot;0&quot;:&quot;all&quot;,&quot;regex&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;message&quot;:&quot;Incorrect value for the field Email&quot;}" required="" type="email" class="cell acym__user__edit__email  ">
         </label>
         <div class="acym__field__error__block" data-acym-field-id="2"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="acysubbuttons">
         <noscript>
            <div class="onefield fieldacycaptcha">
               Please enable the javascript to submit this form             
            </div>
         </noscript>
         <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary button subbutton" value="Subscribe" name="Submit" onclick="try{ return submitAcymForm('subscribe','formAcym73021', 'acymSubmitSubForm'); }catch(err){alert('The form could not be submitted '+err);return false;}">
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

The button isn't aligned with the input fields:
[image]

I have tried like a million things, like:

vertical-align: bottom

As [per documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

And position: absolute margin 0;

Etc. etc.

It doesn't matter: the button is always on the middle.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead use

```css
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```

and also add bottom:0px;

Answer (score 2):

In the code submitted, HTML table is not used properly.

If you want to create the form using a table, the labels for inputs should be declared as column headers, in the `thead` section of the table, not in `tbody`. This way, your table row will contain only the inputs and the submit button and they will have the same height by default.

```css
th {
text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<table>
        <thead>
            <th class="acym__users__creation__fields__title">Name</th>
            <th class="acym__users__creation__fields__title">Email</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="onefield acyfield_1 acyfield_text">
                    <input name="user[name]" value=""
                        data-authorized-content="{&quot;0&quot;:&quot;all&quot;,&quot;regex&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;message&quot;:&quot;Incorrect value for the field Name&quot;}"
                        type="text" class="cell  ">
                    <div class="acym__field__error__block" data-acym-field-id="1"></div>
                </td>
                <td class="onefield acyfield_2 acyfield_text">
                    <input id="email_field_403" name="user[email]" value=""
                        data-authorized-content="{&quot;0&quot;:&quot;all&quot;,&quot;regex&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;message&quot;:&quot;Incorrect value for the field Email&quot;}"
                        required="" type="email" class="cell acym__user__edit__email  ">
                    <div class="acym__field__error__block" data-acym-field-id="2"></div>
                </td>
                
                <td class="acysubbuttons">
                    <noscript>
                        <div class="onefield fieldacycaptcha">
                            Please enable the javascript to submit this form
                        </div>
                    </noscript>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary button subbutton" value="Subscribe" name="Submit"
                        onclick="try{ return submitAcymForm('subscribe','formAcym73021', 'acymSubmitSubForm'); }catch(err){alert('The form could not be submitted '+err);return false;}">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the margin-top attribute? It essentially puts a space on top of your subscribe button.

Basically in the css block of your button, add

> margin-top: 10px;

Note that this value is fixed so it's probably not the best solution but it's a quick and easy one. Also play around with the value until its the right spot.

Comment: thanks, I've tried .acym_module_form input[type="button"]{
      margin-top: 28px;
} and it works, although it seems hard-coded and likely to break on a mobile phone