# Make form fields horizontal on large screens, vertical otherwise

Tags: css

This question is related [with this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73266726/position-subscribe-button-in-the-bottom-of-a-form), thank you!

My form now is tableless:

```
<div class="acym_module " id="acym_module_formAcym77091">
   <div class="acym_fulldiv" id="acym_fulldiv_formAcym77091">
      <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formAcym77091" name="formAcym77091" method="POST" action="/en/component/acym/frontusers.html?tmpl=component" onsubmit="return submitAcymForm('subscribe','formAcym77091', 'acymSubmitSubForm')">
         <div class="acym_module_form">
            <div class="acym_form">
               <div class="onefield fieldacy1 acyfield_text" id="field_1">
                  <label class="cell margin-top-1">
                     <div class="acym__users__creation__fields__title">Name</div>
                     <input name="user[name]" value="" data-authorized-content="{&quot;0&quot;:&quot;all&quot;,&quot;regex&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;message&quot;:&quot;Incorrect value for the field Name&quot;}" type="text" class="cell  ">
                  </label>
                  <div class="acym__field__error__block" data-acym-field-id="1"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="onefield fieldacy2 acyfield_text" id="field_2">
                  <label class="cell margin-top-1">
                     <div class="acym__users__creation__fields__title">Email</div>
                     <input id="email_field_243" name="user[email]" value="" data-authorized-content="{&quot;0&quot;:&quot;all&quot;,&quot;regex&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;message&quot;:&quot;Incorrect value for the field Email&quot;}" required="" type="email" class="cell acym__user__edit__email  ">
                  </label>
                  <div class="acym__field__error__block" data-acym-field-id="2"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <p class="acysubbuttons">
            <noscript>
               <div class="onefield fieldacycaptcha">
                  Please enable the javascript to submit this form
               </div>
            </noscript>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary button subbutton" value="Subscribe" name="Submit" onclick="try{ return submitAcymForm('subscribe','formAcym77091', 'acymSubmitSubForm'); }catch(err){alert('The form could not be submitted '+err);return false;}">
            </p>
         </div>
         <input type="hidden" name="ctrl" value="frontusers">
         <input type="hidden" name="task" value="notask">
         <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_acym">
         <input type="hidden" name="ajax" value="1">
         <input type="hidden" name="successmode" value="replace">
         <input type="hidden" name="acy_source" value="Module n°774">
         <input type="hidden" name="hiddenlists" value="26">
         <input type="hidden" name="fields" value="name,email">
         <input type="hidden" name="acyformname" value="formAcym77091">
         <input type="hidden" name="acysubmode" value="mod_acym">
         <input type="hidden" name="confirmation_message" value="">
         <input type="text" name="my_name" value=""><input type="hidden" name="991b068ee5b7170598a8108feee6a325" value="1659870934.0">
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to style `field_1`, `field_2` and `acysubbttons` to be responsive.

That is, the form now looks like this on a laptop:

[image]

I want it to be horizontal when the screen allows, so this is what I'm trying:

```
#field_1{
  max-width: 30%;
}
```

To make the fields and the button be side-by-side, when there is enough screen, but this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the `<div>` elements that your inputs are wrapped in are block level elements.

Set their `display` property to `inline-block` and they will only push to the next line if they are too large to fit side by side.

```css
#field_1,
#field_2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```